# How to add second axis on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing Manhattan plot for 2 phenotypes and therefore I am melting data for columns GWAS and GTEX in my dataframe which looks like this:

```
   pos.end       GWAS        GTEX
1 16975756 0.71848040 2.82508e-05
2 16995937 0.02349431 4.54958e-11
3 17001098 0.04310933 1.93264e-20
4 17001135 0.04354486 8.52552e-21
5 17002964 0.02352996 1.84111e-15
6 17005677 0.01046168 2.09734e-11
...
```

The problem is that GTEX data is much smaller than GWAS so I would need to have two y axis to represent them.

I am suppose to use something like this:

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis...
```

but I am unsure how to implement that in my case.

right now this is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(ggrepel)

snpsOfInterest = c("17091307")

tmp = read.table("nerve_both_manh", header=T)
tmp.tidy <- tmp %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -pos.end) %>%
  mutate(is_highlight = ifelse(pos.end %in% snpsOfInterest, "yes", "no")) %>%
  mutate(is_annotate = ifelse(-log10(value) > 5, "yes", "no"))

ggplot(tmp.tidy, aes(pos.end, -log10(value), color = key)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(tmp.tidy, is_highlight == "yes"), 
             color = "purple", size = 2)+
  geom_label_repel(data = subset(tmp.tidy, is_annotate == "yes"), 
                   aes(label = pos.end), size = 2)
```

I need to have 2 Y axis one for GWAS and another one for GTEX. GTEX values are much smaller than those for GWAS.

I plotted with the code above this and it looks like this:

[image: a busy cat]
![two muppets][1]

#### UPDATE

I tired to use locus.zoom() from ggforce library but still results is not good. How do I get just the zoomed GWAS values?

```
ggplot(tmp.tidy, aes(pos.end, -log10(value), color=key)) +
  facet_zoom(xy = key == "GWAS")+
  geom_point(data=subset(tmp.tidy, is_highlight=="yes"), color="purple", size=2)+
  geom_label_repel( data=subset(tmp.tidy, is_annotate=="yes"),  aes(label=pos.end), size=2)
```

[image: a busy cat]
![one muppet][1]

#### UPDATE

per suggestion bellow I did:

```
ggplot(tmp.tidy) +
  geom_count(aes(pos.end, -log10(value), color = key)) +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free") +
  guides(size = FALSE) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "grey90"),
    panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines")
  )
```

But I don't know how to integrate in this these two lines:

```
  geom_point(data=subset(tmp.tidy, is_highlight=="yes"), color="purple", size=2)+
  geom_label_repel( data=subset(tmp.tidy, is_annotate=="yes"), aes(label=pos.end), size=2)+
```

If I use it with the above code I am getting this error:

```
 Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y
```

I tried doing it like this but nothing happens:

```
ggplot(tmp.tidy) +
  geom_count(aes(pos.end, -log10(value), color = key)) +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free") +
  guides(size = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = subset(tmp.tidy, is_highlight == "yes"), aes(x =  pos.end, y = -log10(value)),color = "purple", size = 2) +
  geom_label_repel(data = subset(tmp.tidy, is_annotate == "yes"),     aes(aes(x = pos.end, y = -log10(value), label = pos.end), size = 2)
  theme(
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "grey90"),
panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines")
  )
```

Comment: Unclear what your goal is. GWAS seems to vary over many fewer orders of magnitude, but it's not much smaller than some GTEX values. Do you want to shift where the GWAS points are mapped? (Sec axis alone won't do that.)

Comment: You could try to use `facet_zoom()` from the ggforce package to highlight the GWAS entries.

Comment: Hi John Spring I would like to visualize the GWAS and GTEX values on the same plot. I tired to do that (see my plot). GTEX values are much smaller than GWAS values so I would need to do rescaling either the GTEX or GWAS values so that they would be in the same range.

Comment: @teunbrand thanks for the suggestion, I tried to use it, see my update above, but it didn't zoom just the GWAS values. Do you know what should I change to get that? thanks

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that Hadley Wickham is opposed to using multiple axes like this, so it is difficult/impossible to achieve with GGPlot by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to approximate your problem with the `diamonds` dataset. Could you add an identifier in your data and then use `facet_wrap()` on it?

```r
df <-
  diamonds %>% 
  slice(1:2000) %>% 
  filter(price < 400 | price > 3000) %>% 
  mutate(type = ifelse(price < 500 & row_number() < 100, "GWAS", "GTEX"))


ggplot(df) +
  geom_count(aes(table, price, color = type)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, scales = "free") +
  guides(size = FALSE) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "grey90"),
    panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines")
  )
```

[image]

To update your code per the conversation below you would use

```r
geom_point(
  data = subset(tmp.tidy, is_highlight == "yes"), 
  aes(x = pos.end, y = -log10(value)),
  color = "purple", size = 2
 ) +
geom_label_repel(
  data = subset(tmp.tidy, is_annotate == "yes"), 
  aes(x = pos.end, y = -log10(value), label = pos.end), 
  size = 2
)
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for posting this it worked (see my update in post) but I don't know how to integrate these two lines in that code: geom_point(data=subset(tmp.tidy, is_highlight=="yes"), color="purple", size=2)+
  geom_label_repel( data=subset(tmp.tidy, is_annotate=="yes"), aes(label=pos.end), size=2)+

Comment: You just need to repeat your `aes()`. They don't carry over when you specify `data =` in a new geom layer.

Comment: can you please add that to your code I am unsure how to do it

Comment: I updated your code in the bottom of my answer. Hope it works.

Comment: sorry for bothering you but I tried (see the last code above) but nothing happens. Can you please put in your update how my whole thing should look like

Comment: `aes()` was mistakenly written 2x `aes(aes(` try it now

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! Any chance to make the dots size smaller in this code?